# in d3 how to put multiple paragraphs of text including hyperlink into a rect div?

Tags: d3.js

I'm making text box in d3 and need to show hyperlink and several text chunks divided by line separators in rect divs like this and code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35yfL6r1/15/).
However while I can hard code one div by directing inputting HTML into .append('text').html(...), I don't know what's the best data format to achieve this. As I have multiple textboxes, I would need them to read from the data rather than being hard-coded.

I tried replacing text with HTML (as in the commented-out part of data),  but the double quotes in href tends to interfere with the quotation marks on the text field, and the line can get really long. How shall I properly do HTML formatting on textbox in d3? Thanks.

[image]

```
var data = [{
      x: 50,
      y: 100,
      text: "title with hyperlink, para1, para2"
    }, {
      x: 300,
      y: 100,
      text: "title2 with hyperlink, para 1"
    }];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

var g = svg.selectAll('.someClass')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class","someClass")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });

g.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 220)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .style("fill", "lightblue");

g.append("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr('y',10)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.text;
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG has `foreignObjects` which allow to insert HTML directly into an SVG, as long as you give them a proper height and width. To append them in D3, make sure to give the appended elements the `xhtml:` namespace.

```
g.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 40)
    .append("xhtml:p")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .html(function(d) {
      return d.text;
    })
```

```js
var data = [{
      x: 50,
      y: 100,
      text: "title with hyperlink, para1, para2, and some really long text that will wrap"
    }, {
      x: 300,
      y: 100,
      text: "<b>title2 with <br>hyperlink, para 1</b>"
    }];

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500);

    var g = svg.selectAll('.someClass')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class","someClass")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

    g.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 220)
      .attr("height", 40)
      .style("fill", "lightblue");

    g.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("width", 220)
      .attr("height", 60)
          .append("xhtml:p")
      .style("fill", "black")
      .html(function(d) {
        return d.text;
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks @Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen is there a way to make the size of foreignObject flexible such that it contains all the text, or estimate the size/height of the foreignObject to vertically center align it?

Comment: To make the size dynamic, see http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411. To center the text, use flexbox.